# Ubuntu Server on Raspberry Compute module 3

Tags: 16.04, server, lts, raspberrypi, arm

Trying to install Ubuntu Server on Raspberry Compute module 3.

Following the website
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ARM/RaspberryPi I got it running in an RPi3 without a problem but I’m not able to make it work with the Compute module.

Image I’m trying is `ubuntu-16.04-preinstalled-server-armhf+raspi3.img.xz`.

[image: error screenshot]

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/188253/u-boot-bootup-error

Comment: Can you please elaborate on how to debug and fix?

Comment: I am sorry, I have no experience. I could only google someone else with a similar question and _some_ answer.

Comment: ok, thanks, but in this case the answer in that link is not very useful